# JQuery/AJAX: Loading external DIVs using dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to create a page that will load divs from an external page using Jquery and AJAX.

I have come across a few good tutorials, but they are all based on static content, my links and content are generated by PHP.

The main tutorial I am basing my code on is from:
http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/how-to-load-content-via-ajax-in-jquery/

The exact function i need is as follows:

1. Main page contains a permanent div listing some links containing a parameter.
2. Upon click, link passes parameter to external page.
3. External page filters recordset against parameter and populates div with results.
4. The new div contains a new set of links with new parameters.
5. The external div is loaded underneath the main pages first div.
6. Process can then be repeated creating a chain of divs under each other.
7. The last div in the chain will then direct to a new page collating all the previously used querystrings.

I can handle all of the PHP work with populating the divs on the main and external pages.
It's the JQuery and AJAX part i'm struggling with.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sections = $('a[id^=link_]'); // Link that passes parameter to external page
    var content = $('div[id^=content_]'); // Where external div is loaded to
    
    sections.click(function(){ 
        //load selected section
        switch(this.id){
            case "div01":
                content.load("external.php?param=1 #section_div01");
                break;
            case "div02":
                content.load("external.php?param=2 #section_div02");
                break;          
        }
});
```

The problem I am having is getting JQuery to pass the dynamically generated parameters to the external page and then retrieve the new div.
I can currently only do this with static links (As above).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've solved this already, but I'm surprised no one's mentioned to use the ajax() function.

This would allow you to define the request type as GET:

```
function loadContent(id) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "external.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {param: id},

        success: function(html){
                 $("#container").html(html);
        },

        error: function(){
        },

        complete: function(){
        }
    });

}
```

Just call this function instead of using load. Obviously you'll have to tinker with the code (mainly what goes in the success function) a little, but this should give you a good starting point.

Comment: For anyone in future, the above method is what I actually used in the end, although I never got around to updating this post, so here goes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the optional data argument to pass parameters to the GET request. Read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback). This is far better than building the URL yourself. You can of course add dynamic generated data to the parameters list.

Comment: Calling load() with data arguments performs a POST request, not a GET.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadDiv(evt)
{
    // these params will be accessible in php-script as $_POST['varname'];
    var params = {name:'myDiv', var1:123, var2:'qwer'};
    $.post('http://host/divscript.php', params, onLoadDiv);
}
function onLoadDiv(data)
{
   $('#myContainer').html(data);
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#divButton').click(loadDiv); 
});
```

In this example server-side script should return inner content of your div. Sure you can return XML-serialized data or JS to eval etc... it depends on task. The example is simplified, so extend it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks all for the pointers, i'll have a little play and see what i can rustle together.

Comment: Ask for more if this example is too abstract. I can explain it in details, but I think that the common idea is enough to start playing around it.

Comment: I've given the solution a go, but the way I've implemented it causes the original div to be replaced with the whole content of the external page. I need the new div to be added underneath in a chain effect of divs.

Comment: then use http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content instead of .html(). I've just written the common solution. In onLoadDiv() you may apply more complex magics instead of just assigning inner content of container. But I can't provide you the complete solution because I don't have the entire page where it happens :).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial on loading AJAX content is good:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Especially the part explaining how to read the results with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
function GetDiv(id) {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "external.php"
    dataType: 'html',
    data:id,   
    success: function(html){
             $("#container").append(html);
    },


});

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var params = {
    param: 1,
    otherParam: 2
};
content.load("external.php #section_div01", params);
```

will load "external.php?param=1&otherParam=2"

Comment: Calling load() with data arguments performs a POST request, not a GET. You would have to build that URL manually.

Comment: Where in the question does it state that it has to be a GET request? Jet's answer also includes a POST suggestion, and the original poster didn't seem to have any problems with that.