# XSPF Web Music Player and restarting music in surfing

Tags: php, playback

I asked a question in this link;

[Streaming music background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878110/music-in-site-background)

```
function music(){
   $txt = '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
   data="http://***.com/slim.swf?&autoplay=true&repeat=true&shuffle=true&song_url=http:  //***.com/music.mp3&" 
width="200" height="20">
   <param name="movie" 
  value="http://***.com/slim.swf?&autoplay=true&repeat=true&shuffle=true&     song_url=http://***.com/music.mp3&" />
      <img src="noflash.gif" 
         width="0" height="0" alt="" />
     </object>';
    echo $txt;
  }
```

I have added this player with a simple php fonction. The player is working perfect but when page changes, the music restarts. I want that I will be continued.

What is wrong in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Ah, so you are in fact using a player with an autoresume function. Well, then [turn on the autoresume](http://www.boutell.com/xspf/), will ya?

> By default, autoresume is off. To turn it on, you need to add &autoresume=1 to the end of the player URL, as shown here: [...]

**Old answer:**

I'm afraid I think you got this wrong. The answerer in the other question was talking about *creating a whole site in Flash*, something that would enable you to have continuous background music.

It's not easy to get continuous music on a HTML page. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205021/can-you-make-an-embedded-mp3-keep-playing-from-where-it-left-off) for some pointers.

Comment: The question in above link, is my question and about adding continus music in site.
http://www.boutell.com/xspf/

Comment: @Felicita you are not turning autoresume on, are you?